# How to prevent current user's profile from being displayed in a collectionView using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, uicollectionview

I have a View Controller in my app that displays a profile of all users (their profile pics, names, and occupation) through a UICollectionView. I'm trying to get the app to not display a profile of the current user (for obvious reasons), but I'm struggling to figure out how to do this.

I'm using Firebase to fetch users' data, so I have no issue accessing the current user's info. I'm just not sure how I would define the logic for this and where it would be defined. Would it be defined under the collectionView function **numberofItemsInSection** or **cellForItemAt**? Below is what I have in those functions currently.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SearchProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! SearchProfileCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.user = users[indexPath.item]
    
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in your datasource for the collectionview. When you build your data source, compare the `Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` to the `uid` of the users you're adding. If they match, don't add that record to the datasource. That way, you don't have to change the other functions.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to filter out the current user from your `users` array before loading the CollectionView. Let's say you're fetching the users and storing them in your array `users` of type `[[String: String]]` (not sure, i'm guessing since you didn't provide a full code). Then you can create a `struct` like this:

```
struct FilteredUser {
    let name: String
    let occupation: String
    let email: String
    // etc...
}
```

Note that you have to keep a unique ID for each user, in this example it's the email (there are better options like `uid` tho). Also, somewhere you have to keep track of the current user unique ID, for example you could store the current user email in `UserDefaults` (if you use `uid` it's even simpler). Now you can filter the array like this:

```
let filteredUsers: [FilteredUser] = users.filter({
    guard let email = $0["email"], email != UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "currentUserEmail") else {
        return false
    }
    // filter by other values like name, occupation, ... if needed
}).compactMap({

    guard let email = $0["email"],
        let name = $0["name"], let occupation = $0["occupation"] else {
        return nil
    }

    return FilteredUser(name: name, occupation: occupation, email: email)
})
```

Note that you then need to provide `filteredUsers` in your dataSource.